# Trying to filter data and display it on another sheet, however the data isn't fully copied

Tags: excel, vba, row

im trying to filter some data(sheet=`"Imported Data"`) and paste the data that matches to a sheet(`"Test"`). However somehow it doesn't fully work. I have asked this kinda question before, but I've been trying for 3hours now but I can't get it done!

What I want:
- There are 3 single cells which the user can fill in which are the criteria(Collection , System and Tag)
- Collection is a `MUST` fill in for the user, the others can be left blank if the user wants it so. The result must be the entire row(`Column A,B and C`)
- If one, two or three criteria are filled in the chosen criterias must all match to copy to the new sheet (so if one criteria is left blank, the result should be all all three criteria. But the one not filled in can be any value).
- If all criteria match, from the `sheet="Imported Data"` also the value of column E must be copied to sheet(`"Test"`),
this value of column E must be the cell which is in the same row as the matched values.
If you have any questions, fill free to ask... it's a bit hard to explain. 
Thanks for the help in advance! This is what I have now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, zLastRow As Long
    Dim Collection As String, System As String, Tag As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your sheet
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")

    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A in the source sheet
    With SrcSheet
        iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
    End With

    '~~> Find Last "Available Row for Output" in Col A in the destination sheet
    With DestSheet
        zLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    '~~> Set your ranges
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    '~~> Search values
    Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
    System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
    Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)

    With SourceRange
        '~~> Match 1st Criteria
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=Collection, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> Copy A:C. Then match for Crit B and Crit C and remove what is not required
            DestSheet.Range("A" & zLastRow & ":" & "C" & zLastRow).Value = _
            SrcSheet.Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":" & "C" & aCell.Row).Value

            '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
            If Len(Trim(System)) = 0 Or _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Value <> System Then _
            DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents
            MsgBox System & " Not Found"


            '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
            If Len(Trim(Tag)) = 0 Or _
            aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
            DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents
            MsgBox Tag & " Not Found"

            If Not DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents Or _
            DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents Then
            '~~> Copy E:E. Then match for Crit B and Crit C and remove what is not required
             DestSheet.Range("D" & zLastRow & ":" & "D" & zLastRow).Value = _
             SrcSheet.Range("E" & aCell.Row & ":" & "E" & aCell.Row).Value
             End If

            '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
            zLastRow = zLastRow + 1

            Do
                Set aCell = .FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    '~~> Match 2nd Criteria
                    If Len(Trim(System)) = 0 Or _
                    aCell.Offset(, 1).Value <> System Then _
                    DestSheet.Range("B" & zLastRow).ClearContents

                    '~~> Match 3rd Criteria
                    If Len(Trim(Tag)) = 0 Or _
                    aCell.Offset(, 2).Value <> Tag Then _
                    DestSheet.Range("C" & zLastRow).ClearContents

                    '~~> Increase last row by 1 for output
                    zLastRow = zLastRow + 1
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox Collection & " not Found"
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely played: someone helps you. But because of sharing his opinion (a honest and objective reality), you decide to "get the money and run away", without appraising the help. Excellent behaviour you should be really proud of yourself (feel free to delete this one too).

Comment: I do appriciate the help, I only deleted the question because you said it wasn't allowed and the objective of this forum ;).

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the clear explanation. I understand now what you mean and why you choose not to help me. Thanks for your help anyway! I'll try to use to forum in a better way and perform more research before I ask questions.

Comment: No problem (have deleted my comments because were written from my mobile and had quite a few mispellings). You are right on the "doing more research before asking"; not completely right on the "I choose not to help you": I did help you; I delivered a perfectly working code and I even explained you how to include it into your code. Well... not sure if this is a true help (working code for a person who does not seem to have the required minimum knowledge); but, at least, I delivered what you were looking for. You were the one deleting that question (not me), what I found quite inappropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry for that and I meant 'Not helping me in the future' mispell.. That's true, you actually helped me a lot with that answer I've fixed it in the weekend with some of your guidelines to be hones ;). No offence mend, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to use the AdvancedFilter method, but your data setup is important.

I have assumed that your original data has Five columns (A:E), with headers being in Row 1
I have further assumed that the headers in columns A:C are "Collection", "System" and "Tag"
I have also assumed there is nothing of importance on "Test" (If there is, instead of "clearing" the entire worksheet, you can alter the code to only clear the relevant part, perhaps the first four columns.

Set up a criteria range (three columns, two rows) on your Imported Data sheet with the same headings in Row 1 as in columns A:C of your data source.  You could use Data Validation to force an entry; or you could code something within the macro itself.  Or you could develop a UserForm to populate these cells

After your user fills in the criteria, the macro should copy the relevant data.  If all three items are populated, it will delete column D, otherwise, it will delete columns D:E.

If I've made some wrong assumptions about how your data is set up, you may need to delete more columns after doing the Filter.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterButton()
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your sheet
    Set DestSheet = Sheets("Test")
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")

    '~~> Set your ranges
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Set CriteriaRange = SrcSheet.Range("H1:J2")  'or wherever
    Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A1")

'Activate Destination Sheet, Clear it, and run the filter
DestSheet.Activate 'Can only copy filtered data to active sheet
DestSheet.Cells.Clear
SourceRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange, DestRange

'Delete column D always, delete Column E if not three criteria
With DestRange.CurrentRegion
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(CriteriaRange.Rows(2)) <> 3 Then
    Range(.Columns(4), .Columns(5)).Delete
Else
    .Columns(4).Delete (xlToLeft)
End If
End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```